# Tag merge/synonym request: "services" and "service"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

We currently have a [service](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service) tag as well as a [services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/services) tag. Since the only difference appears to be the pluralization of the latter, I think they should be merged and synonymized somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looked like [service](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service) was actually mostly used to refer to network issues, i.e., problems with "phone service".  I replaced it with [connectivity](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectivity) in most places, [services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/services) where applicable.  I think it's probably best to let [service](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service) die out rather than merge with something else.  If it comes up again we should probably rename it to [phone-service](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-service) or something clearer.

Comment: Maybe "background-services" (or something of that nature) would be a good choice to avoid ambiguity if we need it. Swapping "service" for "connectivity" where appropriate was a better idea than merging them, though. I like.